# Forum solution based on SQL Server and Microsoft technology which supports active directory integration

Tags: forum, active-directory

I am searching for popular forum solution (like phpBB forum solution etc) which is based on Microsoft technology and SQL Server and supports active directory integration. Thing is that I use Umbraco CMS and I decided to install nforum but I have many issues with this forum, some of them:

```
almost impossible to integrate with active directory,
many error messages in version 1.7
```

If I find forum solution which I want and based on Microsoft technology, I plan to put it on my website using iFrame and I think that would be the best solution.

Any suggestion is welcome and best regards.